# When I run my test in selenium webdriver, the newly opened firefox window is opened without my installed addons

Tags: selenium, firefox-addon, webdriver

When I run my test in selenium, the newly opened firefox window is opened without my installed addons. Is there any way of displaying the add-ons already installed in my firefox?
Using- Selenium webdriver
Language- Java 1.7
IDE- Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to you use `FirefoxProfile` class in order to run Firefox with additional settings or plugins. So try something like

```
File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi"); //download install file for your extension
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

You can try various things in order to make this work.

- move Firefox binaries to folder on the path which doesn't contain any white characters
- Locate binaries for driver manually
- check your Maven dependecies, you need to have `selelenim
- upgrade Web Driver to newest version (currently 2.35)

`FirefoxBinary firefoxbin = new FirefoxBinary(new File("pathToFirefoxFolder"));`

`driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxbin, firefoxProfile);`

Comment: Hey Petr,
I used your code in my script but it shows an error:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary
 FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe)
 on port 7055; process output follows:
 
null
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.

Comment: I am not sure if the space in the path("Files (x86)") can cause Selenium not finding the binary, so try putting Firefox on other path

Comment: I am sorry Petr but can you please suggest me how to change the path for firefox. Even if I change the path, how will the selenium webdriver be able to locate the firefox.exe file ?